# Archive with months of current year only

Tags: plugins, archives

I'm trying to figure out how to get the following archive navigation:

> JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC 2012 | 2014

Thus, a list with the months of the current or selected year with links to the previous and next year's archive.

I've tried to edit the [Compact Archives](http://wordpress.org/plugins/compact-archives/) plugin, which comes very close to what I need. It displays the months for all years, including those that don't have posts. However, I cannot get it to display the months for the current/selected year only. I know this has to do with the `for each` statement, but my knowledge of php is not that good that I can make the necessary customizations for it to work.

This is what I have customized thus far:

```
    function get_compact_archive( $style='initial', $before='<li>', $after='</li>' ) {
global $wpdb, $wp_version;
setlocale(LC_ALL,WPLANG); // set localization language
$below21 = version_compare($wp_version, '2.1','<');
// WP 2.1 changed the way post_status and post_type fields work
if ($below21) {
    $now = current_time('mysql');
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) AS year, MONTH(post_date) AS month FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_date <'" . $now . "' AND post_status='publish' AND post_password='' ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC");
} else {
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(post_date) AS year, MONTH(post_date) AS month FROM " . $wpdb->posts . " WHERE post_type='post' AND post_status='publish' AND post_password='' ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC");
}
if (!$results) {
    return $before.__('Archive is empty').$after;
}
$dates = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $dates[$result->year][$result->month] = 1;
}
unset($results);
$result = '';
foreach ($dates as $year => $months){
    $prev_year = $year - 1;
    $next_year = $year + 1;
    $result .= $before . '<ul class="archive-navigation-months">';
    for ( $month = 1; $month <= 12; $month += 1) {
        $month_has_posts = (isset($months[$month]));
        $dummydate = strtotime("$month/01/2001");
        // get the month name; strftime() localizes
        $month_name = strftime("%B", $dummydate); 
        switch ($style) {
        case 'initial':
            $month_abbrev = $month_name[0]; // the inital of the month
            break;
        case 'block':
            $month_abbrev = strftime("%b", $dummydate); // get the short month name; strftime() localizes
            break;
        case 'numeric':
            $month_abbrev = strftime("%m", $dummydate); // get the month number, e.g., '04'
            break;
        default:
            $month_abbrev = $month_name[0]; // the inital of the month
        }
        if ($month_has_posts) {
            $result .= '<li><a href="'.get_month_link($year, $month).'" title="'.$month_name.' '.$year.'">'.$month_abbrev.'</a></li>';
        } else {
            $result .= '<li class="emptymonth">'.$month_abbrev.'</li>';
        }
    }
    $result .= '</ul><ul class="archive-navigation-years"><li><a href="'.get_year_link($prev_year).'">'.$prev_year.'</a></li><li><a href="'.get_year_link($next_year).'">'.$next_year.'</a></li></ul>' . $after."\n";
}
return $result;
```

}

I've also checked [this thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39766/getting-all-months-in-one-year-wordpress-archive) but that doesn't help me either.

Comment: If this is a php question then this is probably not the best place to ask it.

Answer (score 1):

I left the plugin for what it was and finally figured it out with help of one of the answers in the other thread I've mentioned. The code below did what I needed.

```
function get_posts_grouped_by_month( $year = null ) {

if ( $year == null ) {
    $year = date('Y');
}

$months = range(1,12);
$posts = array();

foreach ( $months as $month ) {
    $posts_for_month = get_posts(array(
        'year' => $year,
        'monthnum' => $month ));
    $posts[$month] = $posts_for_month;
}

return $posts;
}

function compacter_archives() {
$current_year = get_the_date( 'Y' );
$previous_year = $current_year - 1;
$next_year = $current_year + 1;
$monthly_posts = get_posts_grouped_by_month($current_year);

if ( function_exists('icl_get_languages') ) {
    global $sitepress;
    $current_lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();
} else {
    $current_lang = get_locale();
}

echo '<ul class="compacter-archives-month-list">';
foreach ( $monthly_posts as $month => $posts ) {    
    setlocale(LC_TIME, $current_lang);
    $time = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month);
    $month_name = strftime("%b", $time);

    if ($posts) {
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_month_link( $current_year, $month ) . '">' . $month_name . '</a></li>';
    } else {
        echo '<li>' . $month_name . '</li>'; 
    }
}
echo '</ul><ul class="compacter-archives-year-list">';

$query1 = new WP_Query( array ( 'year'=> $previous_year ) );
if ( $query1->have_posts() ) {  
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_year_link($previous_year) . '">' . $previous_year . '</a></li>';
} else {
    echo '<li>' . $previous_year . '</li>';
}
wp_reset_query();

$query2 = new WP_Query( array ( 'year'=> $next_year ) );
if ( $query2->have_posts() ) {  
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_year_link($next_year) . '">' . $next_year . '</a></li>';
} else {
    echo '<li>' . $next_year . '</li>';
}
wp_reset_query();
```

}